# Problem with dynamic form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dynamic-forms

I currently have my form presenting additions to the form depending onChange of my dropdown selection, however I want it also now do a similar thing on the newly presented input box, so, again using onChange() if the user inputs the number "4" say it presents 4 new inputs. (so i want a loop) here is what I have been trying:

```
var inputt = document.getElementById("options");
inputt.onchange = function(){
var optionValue = parseInt(this.value);
$('#container').empty();
for (i=0;i<=optionValue;i++)
{
$('<input type="text" value=""/>').appendTo('#container');      
}   
};
```

[here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qzhyp/14/) note - ive only been working on the first drop down selection.

ignore the shabby styling, i just want functionality right now.

help please.

regards,

Comment: your provided jsfiddle is wrong, the selected library is MooTools, and it should be jQuery.

Comment: ye that was mistake, i have been actually working with in on jQuery. apologies. Still doesnt work :(

Comment: when i fixed this, I got your code working and providing me with additional input boxs, can you be more specific on what you need to do EXACTLY, thanks.

Comment: you're not even using jquery on your first call(document.getelementbyid)..why dont you use the $ sign therE?

Comment: Do you have a specific question, or do you just want someone to fix your code for you?

Comment: right what I want, is: I click select a drop down option and it presents new form options. When I input a number to "No of options" I want it to present a numbero f inputs depending on the number inputted. And mine currently doesnt do this :S

Comment: @Graza, well Im a beginner and I don't know if I am doing it completely wrong or what.

Comment: check out this, and tell me what you want more : http://jsfiddle.net/Qzhyp/12/

Comment: thats the not the part I was having the problem with, Ive got that fine, I want the onChange to be carried out on the NEW INPUT. if that makes sense? I was hoping I could use a similar script but for a text input.

Comment: @buymypies - check my answer - you want to use jQuery's `live()` method

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Qzhyp/14/ - check this, select Option 1 (Multiple-Choice) you should see the new form inputs appear. What I am trying to do is onChange of that new input (Number of options), depending on what they input, lets say 4, i want to present 4 MORE inputs.

Comment: cool, now i got what you want, wait a minute till i edit your code and add the part that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, I would first of all use

```
$("#options").bind("change",function(){
  //your code here
});
```

rather than setting the .onchange property directly - setting event handlers in this way is generally discouraged, for a number of reasons.

However, your main problem seems to be that you are trying to bind this event handler before your "options" input is even created. If you use what I have suggested above, but use "live" instead, it will work even if the "options" input does not yet exist

```
//i've attached keyup in this example, but you could try modifying it to "change"
$("#options").live("keyup",function(e){
  var optionValue = parseInt(e.target.value);
  $('#container').empty();
  //note optionValue, not optionValue
  //note "<" rather than "<=", otherwise if you type "1" you'll get 2 inputs
  for (i=0;i<optionValue;i++) 
  {
    $('<input type="text" value=""/>').appendTo('#container');        
  }    
});
```

Also be aware that javascript is case-sensitive. I've corrected optionvalue to optionValue

Note: I'm not intending to "answer" your "question" here, but trying to help a bit. It seems to me that your "question" involves fixing your code, so that means that you really need a lot of answers to a lot of different questions. This is just one of those answers.

Comment: do you know any good tutorial sites for stuff like this? Because I am struggling to find sources to educate me, and so I find myself stuck with my code and posting on here lol

Comment: jQuery API docs. They are *the best* resource for jQuery info.

Comment: ye but the problem is, I don't know of say .live()'s existence lol

Comment: Otherwise, it really comes down to being methodical, and working through the problem. It is easy to see here that you are trying to attaching an event handler before the element exists. Then once you've identified that problem, you'll end up with a specific question, which will be a lot easier for people on S.O. to answer for you

Comment: The other suggestion - use the error console in Chrome/Safari or Firebug extension for Firefox. This will help you pinpoint issues, and again, will make it easier to be more specific on S.O. for questions. Dont get me wrong, S.O. will probably be your best learning resource, but it works best when you are armed with a little bit more information about the specific nature of your problem

Comment: ..regarding not knowing of live()'s existance. I highly recommend going through the jQuery docs and just read every single page. It really doesn't take that long. Then if you have questions about anything specific, you can ask there (or here) about it. FWIW, I also didn't know about live() for a long time. It took reading through the docs to learn it - not just reading what you think might be useful, but all of it....

Comment: it's not `target()`, it's `target`. And the reason is more portable code. There's another method "delegate" - which I won't go into here, and you probably wont need it, but if you replaced "live" with "delegate", `this` would be something different, whereas e.target would be as you expect. There are other OO circumstances where `this` would refer to something different. In general, if you can retrieve the element using a function parameter, it's best to use it instead of `this`